# PDF files not displaying drawings in Office Web Apps

Tags: sharepoint-server, office-web-apps

I am facing some issue with some of the PDF files. The files are basically building blueprints and it contains some shapes and markings within document.

When I try to open these files the OWA tries to open them with MS Word engine, and so shapes and markings in PDF document is not displayed. If I open these files normally with browser it works as expected i.e. document shows all markings and shapes.

Has anyone encountered this issue? Is there any alternative configuration for PDF files in OWA other than word engine?

Some articles suggest to remove PDF config from OWA, but I don't want to do this. Is there any other solution for this?

Comment: Whether all the PDF files with shapes and markings have this issue? If so, maybe you need to use PDF viewer tools instead of using OWA.

Comment: Hi @Hellofiona_MSFT, Yes the issue is with all such kind of PDF files. Can you suggest any online PDF viewer tool for SP2013, which does not require application installation on users computer/mobile devices?